# Laravel 4.1 - Controller throw error when I try to load view with layout

Tags: php, layout, laravel-4

I'm trying to load a blade view with layout, but I get this error:
`"Attempt to assign property of non-object"`

The structure is the following:

**Route:**

```
Route::pattern('controller', '\w+');

Route::get('{controller}', function($controller) {
  $controllerClass = $controller.'Controller';
  App::make($controllerClass)->index();
});
```

**Controller:**

```
class PricesController extends BaseController {
  protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

  public function index()
  {
      $this->layout->content = View::make('prices.index');
  }

}
```

The debug says the issue is at line `$this->layout->content = View::make('prices.index');`

The views are fine... I have `layouts` folder with `master.blade.php` and I also have `prices` folder with `index.blade.php`.

The `content` section is exists as well with `@stop` and the `@yield` is there in the layout.

In the `BaseController` there is the `setupLayout` method:

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Why I get that exception?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I helped you in the #laravel irc channel but there are 3 things here for any others with this problem.

1. This is not a good use of route files. Controller implicit routing is hard to maintain if your app gets larger. Consider using Route::resource instead if you're just trying to save a few lines of code. But I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.
2. You'll want to use the `nest` method for your layout, i.e. `$this->layout->nest('content', 'prices.index');`
3. The `setupLayout()` function is not being called because you are calling `index()` directly on the object. This is not how Laravel normally processes controllers.

I'm not going to walk through the entire routing process but if you look at `vendors/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDisplatcher.php` on line 89 you will see:

```
protected function call($instance, $route, $method)
{
    $parameters = $route->parametersWithoutNulls();
    return $instance->callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```

Let's look at `vendors/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php` on line 227 and you will see:

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    $this->setupLayout();
    $response = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);

    ... irrelevant stuff omitted ...

}
```

These reason I show these things is show the magic Laravel is doing behind the scenes.

Basically you are skipping that magic and just calling `PricesController->index()` directly instead of going through the router. This is why `setupLayout` is never being called and you will get an exception because there is no `$this->layout` object yet created.